# C++ Ambiguous over for 'operator>>' in 'std::cin >>'

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, overloading, istream

I am having an issue with an assignment that I am working on. We are writing a complex number class that is defined within it's own namespace. I have everything working except the overloading on my istream and ostream. Let me post some of my code:

```
namespace maths {

    class complex_number{
    public:

        // lots of functions and two variables

        friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &in, maths::complex_number &input);

    }
}

std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &in, maths::complex_number &input)
{
   std::cout << "Please enter the real part of the number > ";
   in >> input.a;
   std::cout << "Please enter the imaginary part of the number > ";
   in >> input.b;

   return in;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   maths::complex_number b;
   std::cin >> b;

   return 0;
}
```

The error that I am getting is the following:

```
com.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
com.cpp:159:16: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ in ‘std::cin >> b’
com.cpp:159:16: note: candidates are:
com.cpp:131:15: note: std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, maths::complex_number&)
com.cpp:37:26: note: std::istream& maths::operator>>(std::istream&, maths::complex_number&)
```

I've spent some time perusing the forum here and stumbled on an answer about name hiding but I can't seem to get it to work with my code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The definition should really go inside the namespace imo. Then both signatures wouldn't need the `maths::` part, and it should still work.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean do not declare them as a friend function (seeing as the values I am trying to access are public I could do that)? Or going about it in a different manner?

Comment: If it doesn't need access to private parts, then yes, it should definitely not be a friend function. All I meant was to put the actual overload into your `maths` namespace since it goes with the class. ADL will find it. However, your point means that no declaration inside the class is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's ambiguous is because you have two separate functions. One resides in the `maths` namespace, and is declared by the one marked `friend` inside the class. This one can be found through Argument Dependent Lookup. You also have a full definition outside of the namespace. Both of these are equally valid.

To start, it's not accessing any private members of the class, so the `friend` declaration isn't needed. Simply don't make it a friend, as that just hurts encapsulation.

Secondly, I suggest moving the definition into the `maths` namespace because it belongs in there alongside the class it's operating on. As said before, ADL will still find it because the second argument is of a type in that namespace, so the namespace is searched and the overload found.

All in all, you should end up with this:

```
namespace maths {

    class complex_number{
    public:
        // lots of functions and two variables
    };

    std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &in, maths::complex_number &input)
    {
       std::cout << "Please enter the real part of the number > ";
       in >> input.a;
       std::cout << "Please enter the imaginary part of the number > ";
       in >> input.b;

       return in;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   maths::complex_number b;
   std::cin >> b; //operator>> found by ADL

   return 0;
}
```

One final note is the overload itself. Input really shouldn't prompt for inputs, it should just read them. This way, you can use it with the keyboard, a file, or whatever other derivative of `std::istream` is desired.

Comment: This worked! So, moving the overload functions outside of the class but still within the namespace. Seems so obvious now, just was looking at for too long I think. Thank you for the other suggestions as well.